# Npm throws error [Opensuse Tumbleweed]

Tags: opensuse, npm

I tried installing node.js on openSUSE Tumbleweed, but when I try to run `npm install` I get an error:

```
openssl fips failed: error:2D06C06E:FIPS routines:FIPS_module_mode_set:fingerprint does not match
```

Any ideas how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The way I got node working again was uninstall the failing node installation and installing it with nvm: https://github.com/creationix/nvm